# Selected elements in Forge Viewer are incorrectly displayed in 2D views on Android mobile browsers

Tags: mobile, autodesk-forge, autodesk

Selected elements in Forge Viewer (ver 7) are incorrectly displayed in 2D plan views on Android mobile browsers. Color of the selected element is not visible in viewer. Everything works fine in 3d view. Model is translated from Revit.

It works in safari and chrome on IOS.

Answer (score 0):

I've confirmed that when running Forge Viewer v7 (7.26.1 in my case) on an Android device, not all elements of 2D drawings can be selected. The issue has been reported to the engineering team.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved in version 7.35